# css transition width and height to 0 on absolute div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

My purpose is to transition a div to width and height 0 thus gradually making it not visible to user.
I have the following absolutely positioned div:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; left: 648px; top: 253px; z-index: 19200;position: absolute !important;" tabindex="-1"><div width: 200px;height: 150px;"><div style="width:150px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">hello<div style="width:50px;height:50px">close</div></div><div id="ext-comp-1060-clearEl" class="x-clear" role="presentation"></div></div></div>
```

When user presses on close div, I attach to the "main" div the following css class:

```
.collapseRecommendation {


 -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
```

and in the javascript (extjs) code set the div's width and height to 0:

```
 mainDiv.setStyle('width', '0px');
 mainDiv.setStyle('height', '0px');
```

and I also set the "main" div different left and top position which does work as expected.

However only the "main" div height and width are set to 0, but the internal's div size doesn't change and it stays on the same place and visible to the user, so after the transition i have the following:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; left: 348px; top: 153px; z-index: 19200;position: absolute !important;" tabindex="-1"><div width: 200px;height: 150px;"><div style="width:150px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">hello<div style="width:50px;height:50px">close</div></div><div id="ext-comp-1060-clearEl" class="x-clear" role="presentation"></div></div></div>
```

As you see the internal div still has size 200x150. 
What can be the reason it didn't become o size as well?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shouldn't expect the child div's size to change, should we?

When it comes to block elements like `div`s, their width only depends on their parents' width because most browsers treat block elements as if they have `width: 100%` set on them. However, when you explicitly set the styling, this treatment is overridden and their dimensions behave entirely independently of one another.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzqcs/1/) shows the behavior of nested `div`s when you do and don't specify their widths. If you click the divs, you'll see them resize. The top divs resize independently; the bottom divs remain the same width. Again, this is because the width wasn't explicitly declared.

The solution is to programmatically change the dimensions of **each** child div. To do this, you could just loop through the children and set all of their dimensions. The code might look something like:

```
var children = mainDiv.childNodes;
for( i = 0; i < children.length; i++ ) {
  if ( children[i].nodeType == 1 ) {
    // Do something with children[i]
  }
}
```